# Passing ID in PHP function which has multiple value

Tags: javascript, php, function

```
$id=$_GET['id']; // this result has values like `1,2,3..multiple`
```

I used this to pass from function `some($id);` in PHP code.

```
In JS file: 
fucntion some(cid){
 // I have check it with alert(cid);
}
```

But it takes or holds only one value here. Why does this happen?

Please help. I want all `ids` in single value (i.e., suppose there are `1,2,3,4`, then they should all be in `cid`).

Comment: use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in PHP,  `split()` in javascript

Comment: @Ghost Rider :-) I wanted to pass that all in single  $id.

Comment: $_GET['id'] is an array or string with , separated value?

Comment: then pass it as a comma separated string, inside the function then split it

Comment: @anant kumar singh $_GET['id']; is value separated by , like 1,2,3,4

Comment: @ghost suppose tow digit value then

Comment: if  $id is a  string with , separated value then pass it directly and then split it inside your function in any manner you want?

Comment: Yes when I pass it but in js some function is has only one value i.e. first one from 4,2,1,5 this set

Comment: Thats why I asked quetion

Comment: @Pratiksha how you are passing PHP variable value to Javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want like this:

```
<?php 
$id=$_GET['id'];
?> 

<script>
var cid = "<?php echo $id;?>"; //pass php value in js
fucntion some(cid){
 // I have check it with alert(cid);
}
some(cid); //calling 
</script>
```

Comment: This should be `var cid = "<?php echo $id;?>";`. Otherwise it will give you syntax error in Javascript

Comment: Don't output `$_GET` directly into the HTML. Ensure santization is taken into place first.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you have multiple `id` parms in you request (checkbox?). Try naming the form input not `id` but `id[]`. `$_GET["id"]` should give you an array then.